# Custom elements on a toolbar (possible event listener issue)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I'm trying to add some custom elements on the trix toolbar using stimulus, but I keep having some problems when I navigate out from the page and come back. At first it looks like this
[image]

and after navigating to elsewhere and coming back it renders the custom buttons "Definition" and "Example" multiple times as such

[image]

and this will keep happening until I do a hard refresh on chrome. The code I have for the stimulus controllers are

```js
// trix_definition_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import Trix from "trix";

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        Trix.config.blockAttributes.definition = {
            tagName: "trix-definition",
            terminal: true,
            breakOnReturn: true,
            nestable: false,
            group: false
        }

        addEventListener("trix-initialize", event => {
            const definitionButton = '<button type="button" class="trix-button" data-trix-attribute="definition">Definition</button>'
            const definitionGroupElement = event.target.toolbarElement.querySelector(".trix-button-group--block-tools")
            definitionGroupElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", definitionButton)
        }, { once: true })
    }
}
```

and similarly

```js
// trix_example_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import Trix from "trix";

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        Trix.config.blockAttributes.example = {
            tagName: "trix-example",
            terminal: true,
            breakOnReturn: true,
            nestable: false,
            group: false
        }

        addEventListener("trix-initialize", event => {
            const exampleButton = '<button type="button" class="trix-button" data-trix-attribute="example">Example</button>'
            const exampleGroupElement = event.target.toolbarElement.querySelector(".trix-button-group--block-tools")
            exampleGroupElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", exampleButton)
        }, { once: true })
    }
}
```

I thought that adding the event listeners with `once: true` would have solved the problem, but no. Is this a problem caused by turbo and I somehow need to check that this only loads once or something related to that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you converting some plain JS to Stimulus code, and, like the blog post in the other answer, I believe it is because Trix editor initializes and fires `trix-initialize` before your controller initializes.

Luckily, if you simply remove the `trix-initialize` event handler and run its body in the body of your `_connect()` function, and update any `event.target` references to some other way of getting at the Trix editor's HTML element, then your code should work.

For example, I was using trix-initialize to instantiate a class called `TrixCustomElement`, which adds my HTML to the Trix toolbar. In the original code it looked like this:

```
connect() {
    addEventListener("trix-initialize", function (event) {
        new TrixCustomElements(event.target);
    })
}
```

And a fixed, working version of that above code instead looks like this:

```
connect() {
    new TrixCustomElements(document.getElementById("blog_post_content_draft"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial adds custom button without the use of trix-initialize.
https://onrails.blog/2018/09/14/lets-create-a-trix-editor-plugin-using-stimulus-js/

Another way is to check and add the button if it is not present in the toolbar.

```
...
const cond = exampleGroupElement.querySelector('[data-trix-attribute="example"]') || false
if (!cond){
 exampleGroupElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", exampleButton)
}
```

[trix](https://jsfiddle.net/p3y1chnu/1/)